# AngularJS how to use orderby with currency values?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to make a sort on my products page. I struggle on ordering prices, right now it orders them as they are strings. For descending result is like:

```
$7.00
$6.00
$55.00
$42.00
```

I want to display it this way:

```
$55.00
$42.00
$7.00
$6.00
```

So I don't have them exactly in number format (they have $ in beginning).

```
   // get sort options
            var predicate, reverse;
            switch ($scope.filter.sort) {
    case 'priceAsc':
                    predicate = 'sizes[0].price';
                    reverse = true;
                    break;
                case 'priceDesc':
                    predicate = 'sizes[0].price';
                    reverse = false;
                    break;
    }

     // order data object
            var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
            $scope.products = orderBy($scope.products, '-' + predicate, reverse);
```

Product array has size array and each size has its own price. How can I fix it, any advise? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think, preferable way is getting from server not formatted price (as numbers) and format it on client with angular `currency` filter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You could try to write your own filter orderby function

```
$scope.priceValue = function(price) {
   return parseFloat(str.replace('$', price));
};

ng-repeat="price in prices | orderBy:priceValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

first: remove $ from price:

```
for (var i = 0; i < product.sizes.length; i++) {
    product.sizes[i].price.replace('?', '');
}
```

Now order your ng-repeat by size, and display with the currency filter.

```
<div ng-repeat="size in product.sizes | orderBy: size.price">Price: {{size.price | 'currency'}}</div>
```